# Probability of a Point Chosen at Random in the xy-Plane

Tags: probability, self-study, density-function

I am reviewing some of my old basic probability notes and for practice I came across a problem that was provided with a solution, but I think the solution the author provided is incorrect.  I am posting here to see if someone can validate my solution, or tell me that the author is right and I'm doing something wrong.

**The Problem:**

A point is chosen at random from the region $S$ in the $xy$-plane containing all points $(x, y)$ such that $-1\le x\le 1$, $-2\le y\le2$ and $x-y\ge 0$ ("at random" means that the density function is constant on S).  Determine the joint density function for $x$ and $y$.

**The Author's Solution (which I believe is wrong):**

The area of $S$ is $(2)(4) = 8$. Because the density function $p(x, y)$ is constant on $S$ and the total volume under a density function above the $xy$-plane is 1, $p(x, y) = 1/8$ for $(x, y)$ in $S$, and $p(x, y) = 0$ for $(x, y)$ outside $S$.

**My Solution (which I obviously believe is correct):**

The author seemed to have neglected that region $S$ is bounded above by the line $y=x$ (the last of the constraints on $x$ and $y$ provided in the question).  By partitioning $S$ appropriately, the area of $S$ is just the sum of the area of one triangle above the $x$-axis, which has area 0.5, the sum of the area of another triangle below the $x$-axis with area 0.5 (the tops of the triangles made by $y=x$), and three 1-by-1 squares below the $x$-axis, each of area 1, for a total area of $Area_S=0.5+0.5+1+1+1=4$.  Because the density function $p(x, y)$ is constant on $S$ and the total volume under a density function above the $xy$-plane in $S$ is 1, $p(x, y) = 1/4$ for $(x, y)$ in $S$, and $p(x, y) = 0$ for $(x, y)$ outside $S$.  Obviously this could have been calculated using double integrals, but the geometry method seemed easiest.

I get 1/4 the author gets 1/8 as the joint density in $S$. Am I right, or not thinking this through correctly?

**References:**

[Hughes-Hallet, et. al. Calculus: Single and Multivariable, 6th Ed.](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP002448.html)  Wiley.  Page 910, problem 18.

Comment: Looks like you are right. Have you considered looking at the "big picture" and thinking of $S$ as the interior of a right triangle with base $2$ and altitude $4$ and finding the area that way?

Comment: I'd say you are correct, but given that I haven't seen the problem and solution as declared by the author, I am not prepared to declare the author wrong.  Typos, silly mistakes, and even deep mathematical errors are not uncommon in books.

Comment: Thank you @DilipSarwate and Mark.  I did in fact look at $S$ as the interior or a right triangle with base 2 and height 4 as well.  My method above was simply my first attempt.  The solution question and solution above is exactly what the author wrote.

I'm happy to know I'm thinking through this correctly!

Comment: Intersection with the set $x \gt y$ splits the rectangle $[-1,1]\times[-2,2]$ into two congruent parts (the interior of each is sent into the interior of the other via the rotation $x\to -x,\ y\to -y$), whence the area of each part is $(1-(-1))\times(2-(-2))/2=4$. That determines the normalizing factor for the joint density.

Comment: @whuber, Good.  That's what I thought.  I think the author forgot the $x>y$ constraint.  If you leave that constraint out, I would get 1/8 instead of 1/4.  Thanks!